# TypeError when attempting to run Node.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I keep getting this error on line 13 when compiling my Node.js app:

```
var db = mc.db('course');
            ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app.js:13:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Here is the code:

```
var express = require ('express'),
    app = express(),
    cons = require('consolidate'),
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    Server = require('mongodb').Server;
app.engine('html',cons.swig);
app.set('view engine','html');
app.set('views', __dirname + "/views");
var mc = new MongoClient(new Server('localhost',27017,{'native_parser' : true }));
var db = mc.db('course');
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    dbs.collection('listCourse').findOne({}, function (err, doc){
        res.render('hello',doc);
    });
});
app.get('*',function(req,res){
    res.send('Page not found',404);
});
mc.open(function(err,mc){

    if(err) throw err;

    app.listen(8080);
    console.log('expres server started on port 8080');
});
```

Can you guys tell me where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this after you declare `var mc`:

```
console.log(mc);
```

You'll see that it returns a `connect` object which contains a `Db()` function.

So you can try changing your code to:

```
var db = mc.connect.Db('course');
```

The MongoClient documentation (https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html) shows this code for connecting:

> ```
> var Db = require('mongodb').Db,
>     MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
>     Server = require('mongodb').Server,
>     ReplSetServers = require('mongodb').ReplSetServers,
>     ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID,
>     Binary = require('mongodb').Binary,
>     GridStore = require('mongodb').GridStore,
>     Grid = require('mongodb').Grid,
>     Code = require('mongodb').Code,
>     BSON = require('mongodb').pure().BSON,
>     assert = require('assert');
>
>   // Connect using the connection string
>   MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/integration_tests", {native_parser:true}, function(err, db) {
>     assert.equal(null, err);
>
>     db.collection('mongoclient_test').update({a:1}, {b:1}, {upsert:true}, function(err, result) {
>       assert.equal(null, err);
>       assert.equal(1, result);
>
>       db.close();
>     });
>   });
> ```

So you can adapt this to your code.  Something like:

```
    var express = require ('express'),
        app = express(),
        cons = require('consolidate'),
        MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
        Server = require('mongodb').Server;
    app.engine('html',cons.swig);
    app.set('view engine','html');
    app.set('views', __dirname + "/views");

  MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/course", {native_parser:true}, function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;

    app.get('/',function(req,res){
        db.collection('listCourse').findOne({}, function (err, doc){
            res.render('hello',doc);
        });
    });
    app.get('*',function(req,res){
        res.send('Page not found',404);
    });

      db.close();
    });

        app.listen(8080);
        console.log('expres server started on port 8080');
```

Comment: hey @mark, thanks its work. and i get it how thats stuff work, and find my error :)

Answer (score 0):

MongoClient instance dont have 'db' method.

Recommend you connect yo db somthing like this:

```
var mongojs = require("mongojs");
var collections = ['users', 'comments', 'books'];
var db = mongojs( "MyDBname", collections);

db.users.find({_id: "abc1234567547abc1c3c35"}, function(err, users){
    // do something
})
```

Good luck